# summation pandas rows and cols for make a plot and a new column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file that represents the evolution of a trend in the market. But the data has a repetition of dates and city names like the df I show bellow.

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    date    city    confirmed
0   2020-03-12  Florianópolis   2
1   2020-03-13  Florianópolis   2
2   2020-03-13  Joinville   1
3   2020-03-14  Florianópolis   2
4   2020-03-14  Joinville   1
```

I just want to make a plot showing a follow up increase day by day of the values in the column confirmed.

I would like to show the increase by day/city/confirmed values.

I tried to groupby but the plot get crazy.

[image]
And I would like some like this:

[image]
Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Paulo

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-03-12','Florianópolis',2],
                   ['2020-03-13',  'Florianópolis' , 2],
                   ['2020-03-13',  'Joinville',   1],
                  ['2020-03-14',  'Florianópolis',   2],
                  ['2020-03-14',  'Joinville',   1]
                  ] , columns = ['date','city','confirmed'])
df.plot.bar(x='date',y='confirmed',rot=0)
```

Comment: Hi FAHAD well I have a csv where I read and have a df with dates, cities repeated like the df I showed and the values associated. Then I need make a group with dates or cities  and show the evolution of the values/cases day by day in the plot. I think it is a little more trick than that. Sorry maybe my explanation wasn't clear enough.